# I am trying to display the data that i have inserted in mysql database. But the value is not being displayed

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to display the name of the user that i have stored in my database. I am not able to retrieve any values. There is doesn't seem to be any error. I think i am not able to correctly access the database, But i can't figure out where i going wrong.

This is my react native code.

```
export default class UserProfile extends Component{

constructor(props) 
              {
              super(props);
              this.state={
                          name:'',
                          email:'',
                          }
               };
componentWillMount() {
          return this.getUser()
        }

getUser(){
        return fetch('http://192.168.0.20:3000/userprofile',{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
              'Accept':'application/json',
              'Content-Type':'application/json',
              }
        body: JSON.stringify({
                  name: this.state.name,
                })
        })
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseData) => {})
        }
render(){
      console.disableYellowBox = true; //// to disable warning :)
      return(
            <Text> Username:{this.state.name}</Text> // trying to display name here.
          );
        }
      }
```

This is my back-end code.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql =  require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
      database:'backend',
})

/* our backend endpoint to check for users ian the database */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

        var name=req.body.name;
        var phone=req.body.phone;
        var email = req.body.email;
        var password = req.body.password;

        connection.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? ",[email],function(err,row,fields){
          console.log(name);
          if (err) console.log(err);
  });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: There's some serious indentation anarchy going on here. Try to keep things organized, especially in a question where people are going to need to quickly understand what's going on.

Comment: @tadman sorry about that. I will edit it asap.

Comment: @tadman could you help me out?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to assign the name in `getUser()`. Won't it be blank at that point? You probably need an API endpoint to get it back, unless that's what your `POST` method does. It looks like you've got things a bit confused here, your update method is doing a `SELECT`.

Comment: What should i be doing? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: There's really too much to cover here in a simple question, but I think if you focus on breaking it down into smaller pieces you'll have more success. For example, your `post` endpoint should be responsible for creating a user. Right now it looks one up. If you can fix that part, then you can wire in the associated code on the other side, which looks a lot better.

Comment: I am not trying to create a user. I already have added a list of user. I am trying to render those users in my screen.

Comment: Then there's a lot of left-over code from something else in there that should go away. You need to render a result as JSON and you need to do something with that result in your React app. Right now you just ignore any data you get in the response.

Comment: Can you tell me the changes that i have to make. Please.